# LayerSwitcher() not working with Group Layers from Geoserver

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver

i have used LayerSwitcher() before and it has worked fine but I am now trying to use it with the group layers in Geoserver and the map blanks out.

```
tiled = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
                    "Geoserver layers - Tiled", "http://niles.iplantcollaborative.org:80/geoserver/wms",
                    {
                        LAYERS: 'Shapefile.py',
                        STYLES: '',
                        format: format,
                        tiled: !pureCoverage,
                        tilesOrigin : map.maxExtent.left + ',' + map.maxExtent.bottom
                    },
                    {
                        buffer: 0,
                        displayOutsideMaxExtent: true,
                        isBaseLayer: true,
                        displayInLayerSwitcher: true
                    } 
                );
var imagery = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
                "Global Imagery",
                "http://maps.opengeo.org/geowebcache/service/wms",
                {layers: "bluemarble"}
            );
                map.addLayers([tiled, imagery]);

                // build up all controls
                map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar({
                    position: new OpenLayers.Pixel(2, 15)
                }));

                map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation());
                map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.Scale($('scale')));
                map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition({element: $('location')}));
                map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());
                map.zoomToExtent(bounds);
```

The moment I comment out the LayerSwitcher(), the map is rendered fine.

Also, I tried adding a new WMS, imagery (in the code above), and if I try to do the following,

```
map.addLayers([imagery, tiled]);
```

I am only able to see a broken image. Can we not add a layer through code with group layers?

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not completely understand your question, but when it comes to layer groups from Geoserver affecting the LayerSwitcher in OpenLayers: this is impossible, OpenLayers cannot tell the difference between a layer group wms and a single layer wms.

As for your problem with "one layer switching off when the other is turned on": This is because OpenLayers treats your wms layers as baselayers. Try to add isBaseLayer: false to the properties of one of your layers (and perhaps transparent: true), then they will show up at the same time

Comment: I think openlayer is considering the entire layer group as a single layer

Comment: Tried `transparent: true` it is the same output

Comment: ofcourse, openlayers treats the layer group as a single layer, that is the purpose of the layer group

Comment: Oh great I thought I could use them separetly, so now i have to load them one after the other?

Comment: if you need to turn them on and off separately, you have to add each as a wms layer in openlayers, yes

Comment: That is the problem I am trying to avoid. See if I add each one of them as WMS, if I switch one on I am not able to see the other one. They are basically point shapefiles which I want the user to see simultaneously. Meaning it will be overlaid on a raster which is the base map. Therefore I have to go for WFS and here is that question. http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25446/unable-to-create-wfs-successfully

Comment: did you set the transparent:true on the wms params object (not the openlayers class properties object), in other words; in the first block of {} ?

Answer (score 0):

firstly I would like to specify that i dont see any grouping definition in your code. i dont know the new openlayers api whether support group layers or not. But you can check out this from old trunk [here](http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/browser/sandbox/jachym/openlayers/examples/layer-groups.html?rev=4958)... and [here](http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/ticket/1086)..

i âm doing it in extjs grid panel as [this](http://jaffa.sourceforge.net/JaffaRIATests/tests/extjs/multigroup/MultiGroup.html). Maybe in geoext tree module can help you...

i hope it helps you...

Comment: by grouping i mean that I have used the geoserver group layer. the `shapefile.py` that you see, are the group layers containing 3 shapefiles and raster.

Comment: oh sorry, someone can misunderstand from your question. you should add **....Group Layers from GeoServer.**

Comment: Done :)

Any solution now how I can resolve this issue?

Comment: The problem with using WMS constantly is that if one layer is switched on the other then turns off. How can I get both on?