# Can feature Info be extracted from WMS

Tags: openlayers-2, wms, wfs

Ok since my previous problem of [overlaying WFS onto WMS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25446/unable-to-create-wfs-successfully#comment34371_25446) is still unsuccessful, I though was able to overlay the WMS instead with this code,

```
{layers: 'iPlant:AllQuebecSpecies', transparent: true}
```

So now I wanted to know can I use the [openlayers get-feature example](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/getfeatureinfo-control.html) to obtain info from the WMS or does it work only for WFS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GetFeature control does not work for WMS GetFeatureInfo. The WMSGetFeatureInfo control does. See http://www.openlayers.org/dev/examples/getfeatureinfo-control.html for an example.

Comment: That is the link that I have added in my question