# Installation issue with OpenGeo-Suite

Tags: ubuntu, boundless-suite

OK so last time had a [big issue with running WFS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25446/unable-to-create-wfs-successfully). Seems the issue was neither with my OpenLayers code nor GeoServer. The issue was with the servers not able to communicate with each other. The tomcat 6 server on which GeoServer was running and Apache server which is the default web server for my Ubuntu.

After some digging around it seems that I need to have tomcat 6 pre-installed on my machine before installing OpenGeo Suite. So having reinstalled the package, at end, the terminal gives me the following message

```
NOTICE: Please run /usr/share/opengeo-suite/tomcat-admin-setup.sh to complete this 
installation.
```

So I executed the following command (from the required directory),

```
sh tomcat-admin-setup.sh
```

And I am getting this error,

```
tomcat-admin-setup.sh: 143: [: Ubuntu: unexpected operator
Unknown distro. The OpenGeo Suite is supported on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5 and 6, 
CentOS 5 and 6, and Ubuntu Linux 10.04 or later.
```

Does this mean the OpenGeo Suite is not compatible with Ubuntu 12.04??

Comment: It seems it's not. Maybe by editing the shell script you could get it installed, but your best option is to stick with supported systems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically the only officially supported ubuntu version 10.04, for which packages are tested extensively on. So i am not surprised there are issues on newer versions.

That said, that script is only mandatory if you want to use a new feature of the OpenGeo Suite 2.5, which is a client app building utility (to be announced officially soon) If you don't need that you can simply avoid running this script.

I will also get this issue filed.

Answer (score 5):

Smaran - here's how I managed to get this done. As jdeolive points out, this is unsupported, and I cannot vouch for how the heck I got this to work. I haven't done a ton of troubleshooting, so it's not really ready for primetime.

I'm making the assumption that you're trying to run the latest versions of various software, like Postgres & PostGIS, etc. Key note: just because you can get all of these packages to install happily together doesn't necessarily mean they've been tested or will *work* well together.

**Steps**

1. Install Postgres 9.1 & PostGIS 2.0 on this page:  trac dot osgeo dot org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiPostGIS20Ubuntu1204
2. Install the latest version of geonode following instructions at:
   geonode dot org
3. Follow the steps below to set up an equivs package for libgdal.
4. Add the opengeo repository info to your /etc/apt/sources.list file.
5. `sudo apt-get update`
6. `sudo apt-get install opengeo-suite`

**Equivs Setup**

The lone dependency breaking opengeo-suite right now appears to be libgdal. Ubuntu and Debian have typically called this libgdal1, for whatever reason. So, you need to trick apt into thinking libgdal is already installed. You can do this using something called equivs.

```
# sudo apt-get install equivs
# equivs-control libgdal
```

then, edit the file 'libgdal' to look something like this: http://pastebin.com/bGUa5BiP

```
# sudo equivs-build libgdal
# sudo dpkg -i libgdal_1.9.1_amd64.deb
```

Like I mentioned... there are a few items I've skipped here, like adding java support for PostGIS and /usr/lib/gdal.jar, etc., but I think you may be able to figure those out. Please add what info you can here.

Comment: I have not tried this @user7947. I will try it soon but on my Ubuntu Server 11.04, the installation was really smooth. I will try you method soon.